# i want to use motion sensor module ouput to trigger a triac

Tags: triac, motion

i am begginer in electronics and this is my first circuit its about a small motion sensor 220v AC switch i want to make myself but i want to use **Triac** as a solid state relay insteade of normal relays i searched alot about Triac circuits and i coudn't understand some of them.
can i trigger the Triac gate using output power from motion sensor module **HC-SR501** without damaging sensor module as shown in circuit diagram??
is it necessary to use optoisolator or can the circuit done using triac only?

Note: i am trying to make the circuit as simple as possible cause i want the final PCB the same size as the HC-SR501 motion sensor module PCB

[image: Switch circuit schematic]

**Edit: using your tips and with some googling around i made that modified schematic, will this work.
i don't want to test until i am sure i will not fry anything.**

i used [this opto-triac isolator](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/SMD-Optocouplers_TOSHIBA_TLP161J_TLP161J_C48237.html) in this modified schematic.

[image: Modified Switch circuit schematic]

Comment: A dangerous first project. Ignoring the many other issues, your first question seems to be whether you can use the sensor output to drive the BC547. You should know the base current required by the rest of your design, so read the datasheet for the sensor module. It shows that the BISS0001 IC is used by the module. Read the BISS0001 datasheet which tells you that the absolute maximum current the output pin can drive is 10mA. There is the answer to your first question. It is generally not a great idea to make a PCB layout if such questions are unanswered at the schematic level.

Comment: i made the circuit using a normal 5v relay on a breadboard and it worked, this means sensor module output can drive BC547, to improve the size i wanted to replace the 5v relay with Triac but i don't have enought knowledge to adjust the circuit to it.

Comment: This will end in smoke and flames if you power it up. If you use an optotriac optoisolator (MOCxxx)  or a mechanical relay to drive the triac you can make it work. The triac may require a heatsink.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany will this be able to drive the triac https://lcsc.com/product-detail/SMD-Optocouplers_JC3H7C_C55287.html

Comment: @SpehroPefhany i am looking for small smd components to be able to make the switch size as small as possible

Comment: On your revised schematic you should be using an opto-triac and not an opto-transistor isolator. See [opto-triacs / zero-cross](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).

Comment: @Transistor thanks for ZC opto-triacs tip, it really helped me to pick the right isolator.

Comment: @Transistor i also found [this SSR chip](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Solid-State-Relays_COSMO_KAQY214ATLD_KAQY214ATLD_C136448.html)   while searching, can it do the task without using Traics??

Comment: It is intended for telecoms applications. I don't think you stated what your load is. 400 V switch rating is a bit low for 220 V which peaks at \$ 220 \sqrt 2 \$ and it only switches 130 mA. I'd get something much stronger.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for quick reply, then i will stick with triac driver circuit. i intend to make 10 switches, stronger SSRs are more expensive than triac circuit components.

Comment: Not gonna put up with you thumbing your nose at us with such sloppiness.  -1 for the disrespect, and closing as *unclear* since I stopped reading on the first line, so I don't know what is being asked.  Go away until you learn some respect for the volunteers here you are asking for a favor.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, first of all I apologise for you, but i don't know what did i do that made you feel i don't respect your efforts in passing knowledge to others.

Comment: For one thing, the first letter of every English sentence and the word "I" are capitalized.  Those are such basic and universal rules, that anyone who can write even a little English must know them.  Not doing so therefore either shows extreme laziness or downright deliberate contempt for the reader.  It says *"I'm so much more important than you dweebs that I'm above your long-standing conventions, and I don't care how annoying it is to read what I write.  You peons have to put up with whatever slop I feel like throwing at you."* -1 again if I could.

Comment: I am sorry for my weak English, I am not doing that deliberately, my mother tongue is Arabic and I don't write in English alot, most of my time I read in English for learning and searching, currently most of my writing is programming code. I am sorry again for giving that impression on my first question. My respects for you and for all the volunteers here.

Comment: Olin can be harsh at times but I would take the same point of view in that this circuit *WILL KILL YOU* if your make one mistake. The suggestion that you use a beefy triac that is mounted to a heat sink is a good one. Do NOT poke your fingers into this circuit while it is powered up.

Comment: @Sparky256 Thanks for your reply, I know working with high AC current is dangerous so I asked first before trying anything.

Comment: Actually I am still improving this circuit, I found out that I can use ZC opto-triac only without triac for loads less than 1 amp and tested it successfully, for higher loads I will add snubberless triac to minimize components number and size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best idea to drive a triac this way. The “ground” potential in your schematic is never too far from the earth potential, while the potential of the hot terminal can swing all the way from −310 V to +310 V. What happens when it swings negative? Well, the negative potential is applied to the collector of your BC547 through the triac, while the base and emitter are sitting near earth/ground. Therefore, the base and emitter become positively biased relative to the collector. Remember, bipolar junction transistors can work even with their collector and emitter reversed (albeit with greatly degraded performance), so, best case scenario, the transistor will turn on and conduct from the emitter to the collector; worst case, the applied voltage will fry the IC.

Comment: What OP refers as earth seems to be neutral and ground symbol is his common negative. Still, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following schematic helpful. This is what a temperature-controlled CT2091 soldering iron looks like on the inside. Notice how terminal A1 of triac Q1 is connected to the ground of U2. This way dangerous potential differences can be avoided. Also notice how the gate drive to Q1 is provided through C2. This way the polarity of gate current always matches the polarity of terminal A2 relative to A1. This achieves two things: square waves at the output of U2 are transformed to short pulses, which is all a triac needs anyway, and the triac operates in the 1st and 3rd quadrants, where the gate is more sensitive.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, but actually this is to complicated for me to understand, i didn't study anything in electronics my knowledege comes from searching online i only love to make my stuff myself at home